# Unable to install Hardhat with npm - "npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, installation, hardhat

```
PS C:\Users\jawad\OneDrive\Desktop\NFT Project> npm install --save-dev hardhat
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jawad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-12T21_20_59_996Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\jawad\OneDrive\Desktop\NFT Project>
```

I'm trying to install Hardhat in my Visual Studio Code project using npm, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. When I run the command:
`"npm install --save-dev hardhat"`

I receive the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jawad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-12T21_20_59_996Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried several solutions, including clearing the npm cache, checking my internet connection, and switching to a different npm registry, but none of them seem to work. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I attempted to install Hardhat in my Visual Studio Code project using the following npm command:
`npm install --save-dev hardhat`

Here's what I tried, what I expected to happen, and what actually resulted:

What I Tried: I followed the steps mentioned in the previous conversation, which included clearing the npm cache, checking my internet connection, switching to a different npm registry, and updating npm to the latest version.

What I Expected to Happen: I expected that the command `npm install --save-dev hardhat` would install Hardhat and its dependencies without any errors, and I would see a success message indicating that the installation was successful.

What Actually Resulted: Instead, I encountered the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jawad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-12T21_20_59_996Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jawad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-12T21_20_59_996Z-debug-0.log
```

Despite trying various troubleshooting steps, I was unable to resolve this error, and I'm seeking assistance to understand the cause of this issue and how to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any npm proxy set? Also, share the npm registry you are using, and `.npmrc` as well (hide any credentials)

Comment: @Jawad You can take a look of my answer, and if possible, could you please remove the in-private information and share the log file? :)

Comment: i don't used any proxy

Answer (score 0):

This issue always come from the configuration issue or NPM unable to send request.

Please run this to check the available registry:

`npm config get registry`

And you can try to put a .npmrc file in the project folder:

[image]

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
                        
always-auth=true
```

If the https://registry.npmjs.org/ url exist and you make sure it is correct, please go to check the network(including the proxy), please check whether https://registry.npmjs.org/ is blocked because of some network configurations.